# TDD - write test first?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, tdd

I am trying to understand what is TDD.

After some reading if I understand correctly - for Laravel development, I need to write some PHPUnit Test **BEFORE** implementing functionality in controllers, routes, model, etc?

It should not be other way around? Implement functionality and then do some PHPUnit Test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.  Following a test-driven development approach to software development your tests will set the expectation for the functionality that is yet to be written.  Therefore, initially any given test you write will fail and you will continue to develop a unit of code until it passes.  It's worth mentioning that in addition to the more common TDD approach towards unit tests, you may also embrace a similar methodology with an [ATDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceptance_test%E2%80%93driven_development) approach towards any potential acceptance tests.